# Setting the price of a custom option with php in magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to update the value of some custom options in Magento, but am having a hard time getting the price to switch. My code is something like:

```
$productmodel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product = $productmodel->load( $product_id );
$options = $product->getProductOptionsCollection();

foreach( $options as $option ){
    $values = $option->getValuesCollection();
    foreach( $values as $value ){
        $value->setTitle("test")
        ->setSku("testsku")
        ->setPrice(floatval(13.0000));
        $value->save();
    }
}
$product->save();
```

For some reason, the title and the sku change just fine, but the price will not change. Is there something that I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you checked removing floatval method before price ?

Comment: Yes, so far I've tried it with every combination of possible variable types I could think of to see if anything would change.

Comment: If you make a var_dump($value) do you see a coloumn price or something that indicates that price exists? I am not 100% sure but you may load wrong structure.

Comment: Price does exist in the var_dump.

Comment: What is the class shown in the var dump?

Comment: I don't see a class, but the object it's showing is Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Value